# C++ - Size of an input stream

Tags: c++

I am solving a [problem](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001) where input stream contains a set of integer numbers Ai (0 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^(18)). The numbers are separated by any number of spaces and line breaks. A size of the input stream does not exceed 256 KB.

My code is as follows:-

```
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    long int index,i;
    cin>>index;
    int *arr=new int[index];
    if(sizeof(*arr)<262144)    // 262144 = 256*1024 bytes which I think might be the size of the array                                    
    {
        for(i=0;i<index;i++)
            cin>>*(arr+i);
        for(i=index-1;i>=0;i--)
            cout<<sqrt(*(arr+i))<<endl;
    }
    else
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with the output generated is that I require the user to enter the number of elements that have to be entered into the array. But the program doesn't want that. It want us to enter the required numbers through the stream but I am unable to do so. Also, I am confused by the "size of the input stream".What does this "size of the input stream" mean ? Can you please me in this ?

Comment: You don't need an array to do this. Just read and process.

Comment: It assumes you use [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) data structure, I guess.

Comment: But don't I need to know how many and which numbers are there in the stream? If yes, then how am I supposed to do that using standard I/O streams ?

Comment: I think the 'whole size of input stream' is a red herring. It's not relevant to the problem

Comment: The 'size of an input stream' doesn't mean anything. An input stream can be infinitely long. It isn't relevant to your problem.

Comment: a tip: you can write `(sizeof(*arr)<262144)` could be written as `(sizeof(*arr)<256*1024)` which makes it much more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of input stream is the number of bytes in the input stream. This part of your code:

```
int *arr=new int[index];
if(sizeof(*arr)<262144)
```

is not correct. `*arr` is an integer and the condition will be true always. Anyway, you need a stack:

```
while (read number)
   stack.push(sqrt(number))
while (stack has elements)
   print top of stack
   pop stack
```

The hint on the size of input stream suggests you can use an array based stack with a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you read the whole contents of the input stream:

```
int n;
while (cin >> n) // this test will fail when we reach the end of the stream
{
    // do something with n
}
```

How this works:

When the end of the input stream is reached, the operation `cin >> n` will fail.  This puts `cin` into an error state.  The value returned by the expression `cin >> n` is `cin`, and when `cin` (or any other `istream` object) is tested in a boolean context, it evaluates to true if it is in a good state, and false if it is in an error state. So the above loop essentially means to keep reading from `cin` until `cin` is put in an error state, which happens when the input stream is exhausted.

So, you don't need to know how many numbers are in the stream from the start, you just read until failure. What you need is a data structure that can expand dynamically to accommodate for all the numbers you might recieve, like any of the containers from the standard library. `std::stack` seems to fit the bill nicely, but `std::vector`, `std::deque` or `std::list` would work too.

If you don't want to use the standard library containers, you could just use an array and keep track of how many valid values are in it. So how to determine the maximum size of the array? You can use the given size for the input stream as a clue. 256 KB means 262144 characters. Each integer(except the first) must take up at least 2 characters, 1 for a single digit, and 1 for the space separating it from the previous integer. So the stream can contain at most `262144/2` integers.

Also, note that the range of the input indicates that you will need 64 bit integers or larger. On most systems nowadays, `int` does not satisfy this requirement. `long long` does though. Or you can include `<cstdint>` and use `int64_t`.